# Kafka Schema Registry flow unclear

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

It is easy to find a lot of examples how to use Kafka schema registry from a technical point, but I'm struggling to find a good practical way to manage these schemas. That means: who creates the schemas, and how does he register it so that producers and consumers can use it?

I know that it is possible to let the producer register its schema with the first message, but as written in some documentation it is not recommended in a production environment.

We thought about having a central repository with the schema definitions and a dedicated service running against the REST endpoint of the schema registry to create and modify schemas. Is there some documentation about best practices relating to the real implementation of schema management?

I read official documentation and also some o'really books regarding this topic but all of them stay very theoretical.

Answer (score 2):

No pattern works best. That's why it's all theoretical.

For reference, at a previous job, we had thousands of schemas at one point, and 3 different environments with distinct Registry servers. Lots of unused schemas were sent to the dev environment, but that's what CI/CD tests were written against to do backwards compatibility checks.

We eventually forced everyone into a single pattern of having a "schemas repo" per project with a well-defined `avro-maven-plugin` pipeline that would not only send to the Registry (with Confluent's own Registry Maven Plugin), but also generate Java classes and a ZIP of the raw schemas to upload to Artifactory for other clients to download using Artifactory REST API... But this was years of effort to arrive at that pattern, and I still think it could have been implemented differently.

tl;dr - For the most part, producers decide the schema. If you have larger, cross functional teams, then producers will be coupled to consumers, and that's a business decision more than a technical problem that can be solved with the Registry.